# SwiftUI: Implementing wrapper around UITableView to achieve custom List-like view

Tags: list, uikit, swiftui, wrapper

I would like to implement custom List-like view in SwiftUI that has to enable more feature than standard native List view in SwiftUI. I want to add drag and drop which doesn't exist in List (in spite of onMove()).

I have implemented this list in such way:

```
import SwiftUI
import MobileCoreServices

final class ReorderIndexPath: NSIndexPath {

}

extension ReorderIndexPath : NSItemProviderWriting {

    public static var writableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider: [String] {
        return [kUTTypeData as String]
    }

    public func loadData(withTypeIdentifier typeIdentifier: String, forItemProviderCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, Error?) -> Void) -> Progress? {

        let progress = Progress(totalUnitCount: 100)

        do {
            let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self, requiringSecureCoding: false)

            progress.completedUnitCount = 100

            completionHandler(data, nil)
        } catch {
            completionHandler(nil, error)
        }

        return progress
    }
}

extension ReorderIndexPath : NSItemProviderReading {

    public static var readableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider: [String] {
        return [kUTTypeData as String]
    }

    public static func object(withItemProviderData data: Data, typeIdentifier: String) throws -> ReorderIndexPath {

        do {
            return try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data) as! ReorderIndexPath
        } catch {
            fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}

struct ReorderableList: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    struct Model {
        private(set) var items : [AnyView]

        init(items: [AnyView]) {
            self.items = items
        }

        mutating func addItem(_ item: AnyView, at index: Int) {
            items.insert(item, at: index)
        }

        mutating func removeItem(at index: Int) {
            items.remove(at: index)
        }

        mutating func moveItem(at sourceIndex: Int, to destinationIndex: Int) {
            guard sourceIndex != destinationIndex else { return }

            let item = items[sourceIndex]
            items.remove(at: sourceIndex)
            items.insert(item, at: destinationIndex)
        }

        func canHandle(_ session: UIDropSession) -> Bool {

            return session.canLoadObjects(ofClass: ReorderIndexPath.self)
        }

        func dragItems(for indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {

            //let item = items[indexPath.row]
            //let data = item.data(using: .utf8)

            let itemProvider = NSItemProvider()
            itemProvider.registerObject(ReorderIndexPath(row: indexPath.row, section: indexPath.section), visibility: .all)

            return [
                UIDragItem(itemProvider: itemProvider)
            ]

        }
    }

    @State private var model : Model

    // MARK: - Actions
    let onReorder : (Int, Int) -> Void
    let onDelete : ((Int) -> Bool)?

    // MARK: - Init
    public init<Data, RowContent>(onReorder: @escaping (Int, Int) -> Void = { _, _ in }, onDelete: ((Int) -> Bool)? = nil, _ content: @escaping () -> ForEach<Data, Data.Element.ID, RowContent>) where Data : RandomAccessCollection, RowContent : View, Data.Element : Identifiable {

        let content = content()

        var items = [AnyView]()

        content.data.forEach { element in
            let item = content.content(element)
            items.append(AnyView(item))
        }

        self.onReorder = onReorder
        self.onDelete = onDelete
        self._model = State(initialValue: Model(items: items))
    }


    public init<Data, RowContent>(onReorder: @escaping (Int, Int) -> Void = { _,_ in }, onDelete: ((Int) -> Bool)? = nil, _ data: Data, @ViewBuilder rowContent: @escaping (Data.Element) -> RowContent) where Data : RandomAccessCollection, RowContent : View, Data.Element : Identifiable {

        self.init(onReorder: onReorder, onDelete: onDelete) {
            ForEach(data) { element in HStack { rowContent(element) } }
        }
    }


    public init<Data, ID, RowContent>(onReorder: @escaping (Int, Int) -> Void = { _,_ in }, onDelete: ((Int) -> Bool)? = nil, _ content: @escaping () -> ForEach<Data, ID, RowContent>) where Data : RandomAccessCollection, ID : Hashable, RowContent : View {

        let content = content()

        var items = [AnyView]()

        content.data.forEach { element in
            let item = content.content(element)
            items.append(AnyView(item))
        }

        self.onReorder = onReorder
        self.onDelete = onDelete
        self._model = State(initialValue: Model(items: items))
    }

    public init<Data, ID, RowContent>(onReorder: @escaping (Int, Int) -> Void = { _,_ in }, onDelete: ((Int) -> Bool)? = nil, _ data: Data, id: KeyPath<Data.Element, ID>, @ViewBuilder rowContent: @escaping (Data.Element) -> RowContent) where Data : RandomAccessCollection, ID : Hashable, RowContent : View {

        self.init(onReorder: onReorder, onDelete: onDelete) {
            ForEach(data, id: id) { element in HStack { rowContent(element) } }
        }
    }

    public init<RowContent>(onReorder: @escaping (Int, Int) -> Void = { _,_ in }, onDelete: ((Int) -> Bool)? = nil, _ content: @escaping () -> ForEach<Range<Int>, Int, RowContent>) where RowContent : View {

        let content = content()

        var items = [AnyView]()

        content.data.forEach { i in
            let item = content.content(i)
            items.append(AnyView(item))
        }

        self.onReorder = onReorder
        self.onDelete = onDelete
        self._model = State(initialValue: Model(items: items))
    }

    public init<RowContent>(onReorder: @escaping (Int, Int) -> Void = {_,_ in }, onDelete: ((Int) -> Bool)? = nil, _ data: Range<Int>, @ViewBuilder rowContent: @escaping (Int) -> RowContent) where RowContent : View {

        self.init(onReorder: onReorder, onDelete: onDelete) {
            ForEach(data) { i in
                HStack { rowContent(i) }
            }
        }
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UITableViewController {

        let tableView = UITableViewController()

        tableView.tableView.delegate = context.coordinator
        tableView.tableView.dataSource = context.coordinator
        tableView.tableView.dragInteractionEnabled = true
        tableView.tableView.dragDelegate = context.coordinator
        tableView.tableView.dropDelegate = context.coordinator

        tableView.tableView.register(HostingTableViewCell<AnyView>.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "HostingCell")

        context.coordinator.controller = tableView

        return tableView
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiView: UITableViewController, context: Context) {
        //print("Reorderable list update")
        //uiView.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {

        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDragDelegate, UITableViewDropDelegate {

        let parent: ReorderableList

        weak var controller : UITableViewController?

        // MARK: - Init
        init(_ parent: ReorderableList) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        // MARK: - Data Source
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            parent.model.items.count
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HostingCell") as! HostingTableViewCell<AnyView>

            let item = parent.model.items[indexPath.row]

            cell.host(item, parent: controller!)

            return cell
        }

        // MARK: - Delegate
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell.EditingStyle {
            return parent.onDelete != nil ? .delete : .none
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
            return false
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

            if editingStyle == .delete {
                if parent.onDelete?(indexPath.row) ?? false {
                    tableView.beginUpdates()
                    parent.model.removeItem(at: indexPath.row)
                    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
                    tableView.endUpdates()
                }
            } else if editingStyle == .insert {

            }
        }

        /*
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
            let object = parent.model.items[sourceIndexPath.row]
            parent.model.items.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
            parent.model.items.insert(object, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
        }
        */

        // MARK: - Drag Delegate
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {

            return parent.model.dragItems(for: indexPath)
        }


        // MARK: - Drop Delegate
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canHandle session: UIDropSession) -> Bool {
            return parent.model.canHandle(session)
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, dropSessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession, withDestinationIndexPath destinationIndexPath: IndexPath?) -> UITableViewDropProposal {

            if tableView.hasActiveDrag {
                if session.items.count > 1 {
                    return UITableViewDropProposal(operation: .cancel)
                } else {
                    return UITableViewDropProposal(operation: .move, intent: .insertAtDestinationIndexPath)
                }
            } else {
                return UITableViewDropProposal(operation: .copy, intent: .insertAtDestinationIndexPath)
            }
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, performDropWith coordinator: UITableViewDropCoordinator) {

            let destinationIndexPath: IndexPath

            if let indexPath = coordinator.destinationIndexPath {
                destinationIndexPath = indexPath
            } else {
                // Get last index path of table view.
                let section = tableView.numberOfSections - 1
                let row = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: section)
                destinationIndexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
            }

            coordinator.session.loadObjects(ofClass: ReorderIndexPath.self) { items in

                // Consume drag items.
                let indexPaths = items as! [IndexPath]

                for (index, sourceIndexPath) in indexPaths.enumerated() {

                    let destinationIndexPath = IndexPath(row: destinationIndexPath.row + index, section: destinationIndexPath.section)

                    self.parent.model.moveItem(at: sourceIndexPath.row, to: destinationIndexPath.row)
                    tableView.moveRow(at: sourceIndexPath, to: destinationIndexPath)

                    self.parent.onReorder(sourceIndexPath.row, destinationIndexPath.row)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is client code using it

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var items: [String] = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            ReorderableList(onReorder: reorder, onDelete: delete) {
                 ForEach(self.items, id: \.self) { item in
                    Text("\(item)")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Reorderable List", displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: add, label: {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
            }))
        }
    }

    func reorder(from source: Int, to destination: Int) {
        items.move(fromOffsets: IndexSet([source]), toOffset: destination)
    }

    func delete(_ idx: Int) -> Bool {
        items.remove(at: idx)
        return true
    }

    func add() {
        items.append("Item \(items.count)")
    }
}
```

Problem is that it doesn't have natural refreshing behaviour of List so tapping + button in navbar and adding items does not refresh my ReorderableList

**UPDATE**

I have also simplified example to test this refreshing of cells as above code is a little long.

```
struct ReorderableList2<T, Content>: UIViewRepresentable where Content : View {

    @Binding private var items: [T]

    let content: (T) -> Content

    init(_ items: Binding<[T]>, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (T) -> Content) {

        self.content = content
        self._items = items
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITableView {

        let tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.delegate = context.coordinator
        tableView.dataSource = context.coordinator

        tableView.register(HostingTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "HostingCell")

        return tableView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITableView, context: Context) {
        uiView.reloadData()
    }

    class Coordinator : NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

        private let parent: ReorderableList2

        // MARK: - Init
        init(_ parent: ReorderableList2) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        // MARK: - Data Source
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            parent.items.count
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HostingCell") as! HostingTableViewCell

            let item = parent.items[indexPath.row]
            let rootView = parent.content(item)
            cell.host(rootView: rootView)

            return cell

        }

        // MARK: - Delegate
    }


}
```

This simplified version also does not work, even when Binding items has new items added to it.

`tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` is called correctly each time I am adding new item but `parent.items.count` is wrong old number

```
▿ ReorderableList2<String, Text>
  ▿ _items : Binding<Array<String>>
    ▿ transaction : Transaction
      ▿ plist : []
        - elements : nil
    ▿ location : <LocationBox<ScopedLocation>: 0x6000016a4bd0>
    ▿ _value : 3 elements
      - 0 : "Item 1"
      - 1 : "Item 2"
      - 2 : "Item 3"
  - content : (Function)
```

even though in constructor or in updateUIView() checking this same items Binding gives correct updated items list.

```
▿ ReorderableList2<String, Text>
  ▿ _items : Binding<Array<String>>
    ▿ transaction : Transaction
      ▿ plist : []
        - elements : nil
    ▿ location : <LocationBox<ScopedLocation>: 0x6000016a4bd0>
    ▿ _value : 5 elements
      - 0 : "Item 1"
      - 1 : "Item 2"
      - 2 : "Item 3"
      - 3 : "Item 3"
      - 4 : "Item 4"
  - content : (Function)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found such trick, but doesn't like this `DispatchQueue.main.async { }` mutating state in `updateUIView()` If someone has a better idea how to solve this problem leave other solution in comments.

As I found:

1. View is struct so each time its initializer is called and there are created new references to items/model properties despite them being class or struct
2. makeCoordinator() is called only once so when there is redrawing there is old Coordinator with old references
3. as we know @State is kept between view redrawings as it has some underlying storage related with it so in each redrawn View model references (different pointers) read from the same underlying storage. So updating in updateUIView() this @State refreshes this state on all referencing paths including one that Coordinator is keeping via immutable parent View reference.

   import SwiftUI

   extension ReorderableList2 {

   ```
   struct Model<T> {

       private(set) var items: [T]

       init(items: [T]) {
           self.items = items
       }

       mutating func addItem(_ item: T, at index: Int) {
           items.insert(item, at: index)
       }

       mutating func removeItem(at index: Int) {
           items.remove(at: index)
       }

       mutating func moveItem(at source: Int, to destination: Int) {
           guard source != destination else { return }

           let item = items[source]
           items.remove(at: source)
           items.insert(item, at: destination)
       }

       mutating func replaceItems(_ items: [T]) {
           self.items = items
       }
   }
   ```

   }

   struct ReorderableList2: UIViewRepresentable where Content : View {

   ```
   // MARK: - State
   @State private(set) var model = Model<T>(items: [])

   // MARK: - Properties
   private let items: [T]
   private let content: (T) -> Content

   init(_ items: [T], @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (T) -> Content) {

       self.content = content
       self.items = items
   }

   func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
       Coordinator(self)
   }

   func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITableView {

       let tableView = UITableView()
       tableView.delegate = context.coordinator
       tableView.dataSource = context.coordinator

       tableView.register(HostingTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "HostingCell")

       return tableView
   }

   func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITableView, context: Context) {
       DispatchQueue.main.async {
           self.model.replaceItems(self.items)
           uiView.reloadData()
       }

   }

   class Coordinator : NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

       private let parent: ReorderableList2

       // MARK: - Init
       init(_ parent: ReorderableList2) {
           self.parent = parent
       }

       // MARK: - Data Source
       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
           parent.model.items.count
       }

       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

           let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HostingCell") as! HostingTableViewCell

           let item = parent.model.items[indexPath.row]
           let rootView = parent.content(item)
           cell.host(rootView: rootView)

           return cell

       }

       // MARK: - Delegate
   }
   ```

   }